# Trigger Verification Email based on roles in Auth0

Tags: auth0, auth0-actions

In my Auth0 application, I have defined two roles:

1. Client
2. Coach

Is there a way to be able to send verification email only for `Coach` role and not for `Client`?

I have already checked [email verification job](https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2/jobs/post-verification-email), and it seems to be working only when the verification email template is enabled.

However, enabling the verification email template results in emails being sent to all new sign-ups, regardless of their assigned role. Despite consulting various Auth0 documentation and community resources, I have not found a suitable solution.

I am seeking a solution to selectively send verification emails based on the user's role.